# Is there a way I can shorten the below query into a single query?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, performance, optimization, query-performance

I have the below query. IS there a way I can put this into one single query? If not, can I shrink it further anyway? Please advice.

```
    DECLARE @highRegion TABLE(regionId INT, countR INT)
    DECLARE @lowRegion TABLE(regionId INT, countR INT)
    DECLARE @midRegion TABLE(regionId INT, countR INT)

    INSERT INTO @highRegion
    SELECT c.fRegionID,
           COUNT(1) AS VALUE
    FROM   census.Country c
           INNER JOIN census.IncomeGroup ig
                ON  c.fIncomeGroupID = ig.IncomeGroupID
    WHERE  ig.Name IN ('High income: nonOECD', 'High income: OECD')
    GROUP BY
           c.fRegionID

    INSERT INTO @lowRegion
    SELECT c.fRegionID AS VALUE,
           COUNT(1)
    FROM   census.Country c
           INNER JOIN census.IncomeGroup ig
                ON  c.fIncomeGroupID = ig.IncomeGroupID
    WHERE  ig.Name = 'Upper middle income'
    GROUP BY
           c.fRegionID

    INSERT INTO @midRegion
    SELECT c.fRegionID,
           COUNT(1) AS VALUE
    FROM   census.Country c
           INNER JOIN census.IncomeGroup ig
                ON  c.fIncomeGroupID = ig.IncomeGroupID
    WHERE  ig.Name IN ('Lower middle income', 'Low income')
    GROUP BY
           c.fRegionID

    SELECT r.Name,
           r.NoOfCountries,
           h.countR AS HIGH,
           l.countR AS LOW,
           m.countR AS mid 
    FROM   census.Country c
           INNER JOIN @highRegion h
                ON  c.fRegionID = h.regionId
           INNER JOIN @lowRegion l
                ON c.fRegionID = l.regionId
           INNER JOIN @midRegion m
                ON c.fRegionID = m.regionId
           INNER JOIN census.Region r
                ON  c.fRegionID = r.RegionID
```

Comment: Is this for performance or just make the syntax shorter?

Comment: Why don't you give your income groups categories? Then you could do this a lot more "normally"...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you should be able to do it, with something like this:

```
SELECT r.Name,
       r.NoOfCountries,
       sum(case when ig.Name IN ('High income: nonOECD', 'High income: OECD') then 1 else 0 end) AS HIGH,
       sum(case when ig.Name IN ('Lower middle income', 'Low income') then 1 else 0 end) AS LOW,
       sum(case when ig.Name = 'Upper middle income' then 1 else 0 end) AS mid 
FROM   census.Country c
       INNER JOIN census.Region r
            ON  c.fRegionID = r.RegionID
       INNER JOIN census.IncomeGroup ig
            ON  c.fIncomeGroupID = ig.IncomeGroupID
group by 
    r.Name,
    r.NoOfCountries
```